# Example for i18n in Play 2.0 (Scala)

Tags: scala, internationalization, playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm looking for an example for i18n in Play 2.0 (Scala).

Answer (score 6):

It is the same as how you would have done this is in Play 1.x Scala, which is

```
@main(title = "The title") {

   <p>Hello world in @Messages("yourmessage")</p>

}
```

For the full documentation though, check it out here - https://github.com/playframework/Play20/wiki/ScalaI18N

Comment: I think you don't even need the import.

Answer (score 2):

The Scala API is slightly different. You don't need to call ".get". It's working without the import.

```
<p>Hello world in @Messages("yourmessage")</p>
```

Also check out this example, which supports two languages:
https://github.com/julienrf/chooze

Answer (score 1):

Here is another example using c10n library:

- [Using c10n with Scala](https://github.com/rodionmoiseev/c10n/wiki/Scala-Integration)
- [Details on integrating c10n with Play 2.0](https://github.com/rodionmoiseev/c10n/wiki/Play-Framework-2.0-Integration)